# AC Analog Isolation

Tags: ac, analog, opto-isolator

Please excuse my limited knowledge of electronics, my problem is I've a circuit which is driven by a variable AC signal using LabVIEW it ranges from 100Hz to 100kHz (I can lower this to 30-50kHz if needs be). I need to isolate the output of this circuit, but the signal needs to remain unchanged i.e I need both positive and negative (well I think I do, I'm open to reasons why not). The output signal will be then passed through the load sample and I'll be using labview to acquire the peak to peak of the resulting potential across the load and also phase shift vs the input.

I have some optoisolators already, HCPL-7800A and a HCNR201, I'm unsure if any of these are suitable as due to their nature with LED's, half the signal will be clipped as far as I'm aware.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you say "isolate", what exactly do you mean? I.e. what are your isolation requirements?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, sorry I should of clarified that, I need to isolate the output from electrical current, specifically current passing from the mains to the sample due to a possible fault somewhere in the device, the project is a proof of concept for medical applications, so the sample needs to be electrically isolated to comply with IEC 60601

Comment: Will the HCPL-7800A chip do what my requirements require? And if so could someone give me a quick explanation of the surrounding circuitry to get it working? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

There are dedicated chips for isolating analog signals. Depending on cost, bandwidth, accuracy and isolation grade you can select one of these. I have used Avago's HCPL ICs. I believe they also have an ACPL series.

You could also do this "from scratch" - A/D converter, optocoupler to transmit digital data, followed by a D/A.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm almost finished a Physics degree so my electronics knowledge is limited to say the least. I have a HCPL-7800A chip which matches my bandwidth requirements up to 100kHz, I've got the datasheet also but I'm struggling to understand how to implement it in my circuit, it's obviously not as simple as powering the chip and input in, and output out. Are these chips capable of isolating analog AC signal leaving them unchanged?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. From your remarks I'm guessing you will need help from someone with a little EE exprerience to look at your design.